# Authenticating with JWT on DRF tests

Tags: testing, django-rest-framework, jwt

I've been struggling to find proper information on how to authorize DRF test client via JWT, so I can make tests like.

```
class TestUserAPI(APITestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        users = UserFactory.create_batch(10)
        cls.users_content = json.dumps(
            [{'email': user.email} for user in users]
        )

    def test_GET_users_list(self):
        response = self.client.get('users:user_list_create')
        data = json.loads(response.content)
        assert self.users_content in data
```

Btw, I'm using jazzband's Simple JWT.

A little help would be appreciated and sorry if you find any grammar errors, english is not my native language.

Comment: Use [**`force_authenticate(...)`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#forcing-authentication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, I do something like this:

```
    from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import AccessToken

    class TestUserAPI(APITestCase):
    
        @classmethod
        def setUpTestData(cls):
            users = UserFactory.create_batch(10)
            cls.users_content = json.dumps(
                [{'email': user.email} for user in users]
            )
            # create token for an existing user to use later
            token = str(AccessToken.for_user(users[0]))
    
        def test_GET_users_list(self):
            self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Bearer ' + self.token)
            response = self.client.get('users:user_list_create')
            data = json.loads(response.content)
            assert self.users_content in data
```

**NOTE**:

you can use `response.json()` instead of `json.loads(response.content)`